# Ассоциативный массив php

Tags: php, массивы

Например, есть массив:

```
$test = array(
    "param240"=>1,
    "pwr_int"=>9.349000,
    "pwr_ext"=>13.031000,
    "param23"=>107,
    "param199"=>4
);
```

Как вывести список его параметров? Например:

```
param240
pwr_int
pwr_ext
param23
param199
```

Значения этих элементов меня не волнует.
Волнует список элементов ! Спасибо :)

Comment: Эм.. Почему в массиве 5 ключей, а в желаемом выводе только 3? UPDATE: А, разобрался. Вопрос криво сформулирован.

Comment: И да, у кого там больше не воспроизводится вопрос "как получить список всех ключей массива"? о_О Лучше плюсуем правильный ответ и больше не трогаем вопрос.

Answer (score 7):

Используйте функцию [array_keys()](http://www.php.ru/manual/en/function.array-keys.html).

Comment: Спасибо :) ... Очень сильно меня выручил :) +100 :)
* А я старый дурила :)

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($массив as $ключ => $значение) {
    echo $ключ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Кроме указанных выше, есть еще встроенная функция print_r($array), которую можно использовать для вывода массива. Она часто используется при тестировании скриптов, но при реальной работе реже ибо выводит массив по такой схеме:
     Array
     {
     [ключ N]=>значение N
     }